# Information on open soucre ALM tools

Tags: alm

My objective is to have traceability between requirement, design, test case and test results of a project. Can any one give me the details of such an ALM tool . It should be an open source tool.

Comment: Can you provide a little context? What languages do you use? What operating systems are you familiar with? Why the preference for open source tools?

Answer (score 1):

There are many tools for this. The first Question as always is: which programming language is this for? How big is the Team (including the specialist division which use these tools => requirements)?

Suggesting JAVA is the language, I'd prefer these tools:

**Requirements**: JIRA (not free but best!), Mantis or Bugzilla also may do an acceptable job

**Design**: depending on which design? To use UML a good choice had been TogetherJ (RIP => now part of Borland's toolbox); you may try ArgoUML or WhiteStarUML; using a Wiki I'd suggest e.g. DokuWiki and a good Office System is also a choice - depending on the needs within your team! (Yes a design always includes text)

**test case**: I'd like to split this topic a bit to “test planning” and “test execution” an last but not least “test documentation”

- **test planning** : give TestLink a research
- **test execution**: (free of charge!) Jubula, JUnit, Selenium => depending on your needs
- **test documentation**: you should use a standard Editor like Word or Writer etc. (not the Wiki)

Additional perspectives:

**build server**: I've missed the build server within your list: if you code a piece of software how do you certain the software can be build also if a machine or a person refuse to work (on any reasons)? Building a software on the developer’s machine includes exactly the risc that the SW may not be buildable of another machine/by another person. So use a build server (where jenkins/hudson should be on your short list)

**repository**: according to the topic on saving the sourcecode within a CVS you probably also ensure to have an access to all the used external libraries you need within your program. Try artifactory or nexus

**clearing process**: If you work within a company’s team where the company’s strategy is actually to test a software before publishing the software you you’d think of a clearing process according to the test results. You should think about the group of people who should be involved within the clearing process of the software. Get them as partner into your project – otherwise it’ll be hard!

I hope the answer was helpful and fits to your needs?! 
ALM is a huge topic and here we're discussing just a part of SDLC which is ONE topic in ALM.